# throw error if new properties are added after object has been frozen

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using JavaScript/Node.js, is it possible to throw an error if an object is modified after being frozen? I want to put an immutable property on an object and also prevent the object from being reassigned.

In this case, I am writing a library, and I need the assignment `module.exports = x;` to be immutable.

I want to prevent the user from adding properties to x as well as preventing module.exports from being reassigned. Not only that, but instead of a silent error, I would like to throw an error if the user attempts the above, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If the users code is running in strict mode, it will automatically throw an error.

```js
function log(obj) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) + '\n';
}

function nonStrict(obj) {
  obj.b = 2;
  log(obj);
}

function strict(obj) {
  'use strict';
  try {
    obj.b = 2;
  } catch(e) {
    log(e.message);
  }
}

var obj = {
  a: 1
};
Object.freeze(obj);
nonStrict(obj);
strict(obj);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.freeze(x);`.

For example in the module `foo.js`

```
var foo = {id: 42};

Object.freeze(foo);

module.exports = foo;
```

In the module `bar.js` you get the error.

```
'use strict';

var foo = require('./foo');

foo.bar = 42; // TypeError: Can't add property bar, object is not extensible
```

Note that to throw the error you need to use the strict mode. If you don't use that, the object will continue to be immutable, but it just don't throw errors.